# Global object constructor isn't getting called

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor

Somehow my global objects are created without having their respective constructors called:

```
static int num = 0;
class TestClass
{
public:
    int a;
    float b;
    TestClass(float f)
    {
        a = 55;
        b = f;
        ++num;
    }
};
TestClass test(32);

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    std::cout<<"Int: "<<test.a<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Float: "<<test.b<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Constructor has been called "<<num<<" times"<<std::endl;
    while(true);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Int: 0
Float: 0
Constructor has been called 0 times
```

I've used constructors like this in different projects before and never ran into any problems like this.
I've tried a parameterless constructor and making the test-variable static, neither had any different effect.
Can anyone enlighten me about what's going on here?

I'm using visual studio 2010, in case that makes any difference.

Comment: In case anyone's interested, [on ideone](http://ideone.com/3pnvDc) it works just fine.

Comment: Your code gives me the correct output.

Comment: Is this your exact code? Specifically are the global `TestClass test` and `int num` counter in the same file?

Comment: Yes, it's all in the same file and I've tried it with this exact code. And no, I haven't changed the entry point, just checked it to be sure.

Comment: Just ran the code on VS 2010 as well, also no problems, prints expected values.

Comment: @Silverlan does this **exact** code demonstrate the issue on your machine?

Comment: @Silverlan well it can't be this *exact* code since this is missing `#include <iostream>`.

Comment: VS 2012 produces the expected output as well. Is this code in a library? If yes, you might want to check my answer below.

Comment: voting to close as the posted code does not reproduce the problem

Comment: `while(true);` is UB BTW...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not completely sure but this might answer your question: http://www.nsnam.org/docs/linker-problems.doc

**Edited to add more information**:

The document points out problems that can occur when using global constructors in different compilation units. For example if you define an object globally in some dynamically linked library, its object constructor might not be called when accessing a method from this library.

To use the example from the original question: The class `TestClass` and the global object `test` might be in `TestLibrary.dll` while the `main()` function is in some executable file. Depending on how the `TestLibrary.dll` is loaded and the `test` object is accessed from the executable, its constructor might never get called because the library is never "informed" that it was just loaded (or to put it differently: the global initialization function was never called).

Comment: Could you summarize the contents of this link for those who don't have Word and in case the link stops working?

Comment: ... and specifically which part of the 17 page document fixes the problem. Useful links are encouraged, but they should generally be comments instead of answers, **unless** you **fully** answer the question and just include the link in a "this is where I found it" kind of way.

Comment: You're right. Sorry. I just added some more information to make this answer more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile your project, which you link into your Executable, to an Executable-File, Visual Studio will link everything fine, but your Global-Constructor will not get invoked.