# Why are exceptions thrown during deferred dynamic initialization not caught by main?

Tags: c++, exception, language-lawyer, function-try-block

The wording which confuses me is this:

> It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-block non-inline variable with static storage duration is sequenced before the first statement of main **or is deferred**.
> If it is deferred, it strongly happens before any non-initialization odr-use of any non-inline function or non-inline variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized. It is implementation-defined in which threads and at which points in the program such deferred dynamic initialization occurs.

- [[basic.start.dynamic] p5](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.dynamic#5)

In practice, this means that:

```cpp
int do_throw() { throw 0; }

int x = do_throw(); // It is implementation-defined whether an exception is 
                    // thrown before main() or inside main().

int main() try {
    // an exception could be thrown here because we aren't using main()
    // (main can't be used, see [basic.start.main])
    return x;
} catch (...) {}
```

*Note: merely defining `main` isn't odr-use of the function, see [[basic.def.odr] p8](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#8). This makes it valid to sequence `do_throw()` inside `main`.*

If the initialization is deferred, and the odr-use of `x` inside `main` triggers dynamic initialization *inside* `main`, it would be reasonable to believe that the *function-try-block* around `main` catches the exception. However:

> Exceptions thrown in [...] or in constructors of objects associated with non-block variables with static storage duration are not caught by a *function-try-block* on the main function.

- [[except.handle] p11](https://eel.is/c++draft/except.handle#11)

Contrary to intuition, the *function-try-block* on `main` would not catch the exception, even if the dynamic initialization of `x` is deferred.

#### Questions

Is this an oversight? Is it intentional? Do `try` blocks ignore deferred dynamic initializaton in general, or is it just the *function-try-block* on main?

How would you even implement this?! The *function-try-block* on `main` would have to selectively ignore some exceptions that originate from deferred dynamic initialization, but catch exceptions from other sources.

#### Further thoughts

The implied behavior is extremely surprising:

```cpp
int main() try {
    throw 0; // safe
} catch (...) {}

int main() try {
    return x; // std::terminate is called because of an uncaught exception ?!?!
} catch (...) {}

int main() {
    try {
        return x; // safe ?!
    } catch(...) {}
}
```

*Note: the `try` block is first statement inside `main`, so if deferring takes place, `return x` cannot be sequenced before `try`. I'm not sure if this is even implementable, because `main` only has one statement (unless we consider all statements recursively).*

Comment: It would surprise me if exception would be caught in main.

Comment: I don't think that this is either an oversight, or intentional. This is C++.

Comment: @Jarod42 If `do_throw()` is called inside `main`, why would it surprise you that an exception thrown by `do_throw()` is caught by `main`?

Comment: *"How would you even implement this?!"* `x = [](){try {return do_trow();} catch(...) { std::terminate();}}();`?

Comment: @Jarod42 this becomes impractical when you nest the first odr-use of `x` deeply inside functions called within `main`. You would need to flag exceptions of deferred dynamic initialization as not catchable by `main` or something.

Comment: sure, maybe here it's obvious that `main()` should catch it. But what about `std::thread([]{ return x; });`? In this case, the exception occurs on a thread that isn't running `main`.

Comment: @RaymondChen then the initialization would take place on another thread and there is no expectation that the exception would be caught by a *function-try-block* on `main`. Nothing surprising there.

Comment: An implementation could do this: `int x; struct initialize_x { initialize_x() noexcept { x = do_throw(); } } hidden_initializer_for_x;` and always defer `x` and its initializer together. In practice, deferral occurs when the variable is in a separate dynamic library from `main`. The exception is raised when the dynamic library is loaded, and there is a `catch()` in the dynamic library code for exceptions that are thrown when static variable initialization fails. The standard is saying "it's okay to std::terminate in that catch."

Comment: I don't see how it is impractical, the hard part is to place `void deferred_init_x() noexcept` call at good places, but then code similar to my comment should do the job.

Comment: Note also the requirement "it **strongly happens before** any non-initialization odr-use of any non-inline function or non-inline variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized." So even in your example, if `x`'s initialization is deferred, it then must be un-deferred before `main` starts. "An exception could be thrown here" is incorrect. It must be thrown before the function (`main`) starts.

Comment: *"In practice, this means that..."* Is there a implementation that defers initialization in practice? I don't think there's one. (Not counting `thread_local` variables.)

Comment: @RaymondChen it says "is sequenced before the first statement of `main` ***OR***" so I don't know what you mean by "un-deferred". It looks to me like this implies that the execution happens (or could happen) someplace inside `main` when deferral happens.

Comment: @Jarod42 it's not necessarily `noexcept` though. Why would it be `noexcept` when deferral seemingly can be implemented by just making the call inside `main`, and when seemingly regular `try` blocks can catch the exceptions thrown during deferral. The wording would have to outright say that any exceptions thrown during deferred dynamic initialization result in `std::terminate`, otherwise `noexcept` doesn't seem valid.

Comment: If the intention is just that dynamic libraries can perform initialization of globals after `main()` has already been entered, then I think there is a defect in the standard. The wording should be stronger and forbid exceptions for deferred dynamic initialization.

Comment: (Sorry, by "undefer" I meant "initialization of a deferred variable." The sentence says "If it [the initialization] is deferred, it [the initialization] strongly happens before" the use of any function or variable in the same TU. Since the deferred variable `x` is in the same `TU` as `main`, it must be initialized before `main` starts. Since `main` isn't even running at the point the initialization occurs, it cannot possibly catch the exception.

Comment: @RaymondChen the wording in [basic.start.dynamic] p5 suggests quite strongly that the initialization can take place once `main` has already been entered. Deferring would be quite meaningless otherwise.

Comment: If your example had used the variable `x` from some function `oops()` that was called from `main`, then `x` can be initialized after `main` starts and before `oops()` starts. But using the variable `x` from within `main` itself forces `x` to be initialized before `main` starts.

Comment: I don't see any wording that supports this claim. Initializing inside `main` satisfies the requirement that the initialization takes place before the first non-initialization odr-use of `x`. And transfer of control between functions isn't observable anyway, so it can't possibly have an impact whether we throw in `main` or in `oops`. (other than some implementation-defined effect on stack traces)

Comment: The current wording is *stronger* than "an exception may not be thrown from the initializer of a variable whose initialization has been deferred." Your suggestion makes throwing an exception UB, which invalidates the whole program! The current wording says "No, this is still a valid program. The implementation must execute the initialization in the normal way, and if an exception occurs, it must be treated as an unhandled exception."

Comment: "Initializing inside main satisfies the requirement that the initialization takes place before the first non-initialization odr-use of x." That's not what the clause says. It says that the initialization takes place before the first non-initialization odr-use of *any function or variable in the same TU*. And `main` is in the same TU as `x`, so `x` must be initialized before `main`.

Comment: @RaymondChen I was suggesting that throwing from deferred initialization would result in `std::terminate` being called. The same applies to unhandled excetpions in general. There is no difference.

Comment: @RaymondChen the `main` function can't be used. (https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#3). Writing code inside `main` doesn't count, assuming that "use" refers to odr-use here, which it probably does.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying about `std::terminate`. Note that your example is confusing because you are using `main` in two ways. (1) as its special status as the program entry point, (2) as one of many possible ways of using the `x` variable. This makes it subject to two sets of constraints (some mandatory and some optional), and since there are conflicts, the mandatory constraints win.

Comment: `main` isn't "used" at all. Defining `main` as an entry point doesn't count as use, otherwise the mentioned paragraph would be violated and all C++ programs would be ill-formed. Also *"A function is odr-used if it is named by a potentially-evaluated expression or conversion."* (https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#8), so it doesn't look like any use of `main` takes place at all, and it would be valid to defer initialization until *inside* `main`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I think deferred-init is done in practice with dll. Auto-registration code even fails in some circumstance.

Comment: @Jarod42 Hmm, do you remember the details? We rely heavily on auto-registration code, and until now it has worked.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Too vaguely sorry... found [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16801675/2684539).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: [avoid-unused-variables-get-optimized-out-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77310618/avoid-unused-variables-get-optimized-out-in-c) seems to have that issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    return x; // safe ?!
} catch(...) {}
```

that is not safe.

> If it is deferred, it strongly happens before any non-initialization odr-use of any non-inline function or non-inline variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized. It is implementation-defined in which threads and at which points in the program such deferred dynamic initialization occurs.

The initialization of `x` strongly happens before the use of `x` here, but where it happens is implementation defined.

The compiler is free to have `main` wait while it spawns a new thread, that new thread instantiates `x`, an uncaught exception occurs, and the program terminates (I suspect it is legal for this extra thread to have no active handler? - but I could be wrong, in which case things get strange).

It is free to initialize `x` before the `try`, and similarly terminate the program.

...

However, I suspect this is not intended.  I suspect that the function-try block clause exists because it there are implementations of C++ in which how static initialization occurs is that a table of such initialization is built (at compile time), and `main` has initialization code injected into it.

In such a model, having function-try blocks catch exceptions in that initialization makes perfect implementation sense.  However, in other models it doesn't.  So to deal with "do exceptions get caught when a static global fails to be constructed", they added that clause.  You'll note that absent that clause and deferred initialization everything would be clear.

But deferred initialization and that clause together do act strange.

I suspect strongly that the only sane way to deal with an exception in a static global variable is `std::terminate`.  Barring this to be "safe" you'd have to deal with the possibility of the first access to a symbol in a random file could throw an error (not just access to `x`, but access to any symbol in `x`'s file!), which would require intense knowledge of the file-structure of every library to determine what exceptions you need to catch.

I think the deferred clause exists to allow for something like dynamic loading of translation units.  So before you ODR-use anything in that file, all of the static globals are constructed; this might happen as the compiler loads the library containing the translation unit in question.

Annoyingly, it also permits elimination of static globals via translation unit garbage collection.  If nobody ever accesses a symbol in a file, there is no ODR-use that requires happens-before initialization of the globals in the file.

Comment: `return x` is safe (or at least possibly is). The quote says "before the first statement of `main` ***OR*** is deferred", and the first statement of `main` is the try block. This means that if deferring takes places, it would be illegal to sequence `return x;` before `try`.

Comment: Actually I guess it depends on whether the *block-statement* which comprises the entirety of `main` is meant by "the first statement", or whether this refers to the first statement within the *block-statement*. There are two interpretations and the standard is ambiguous here.

Comment: I'm reading "Happens-before" as a memory model statement, as I the rest of the sequencing statements here.  The thread the initialization occurs on is *implementation defined*, so while it happens-before `return x`, it doesn't have to happen on the main thread at all, and may be *unsequenced* with respect to anything else before `return x` in main.  `try` itself is flow control, and as far as I know sequencing relative to *try* is meaningless.

Comment: So while `do_throw()` *happens-before* `return x`, it could happen unsequenced with respect to `printf("hello")` where `main` starts with `try { printf("hello"); return x; }`, and in fact unsequenced with respect to the start-of-main.

Answer (score 0):

It is irrelevant, because an exception thrown from the initialization of a non-block static storage duration variable always calls `std::terminate` according to [[basic.start.dynamic]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic#start.dynamic-8). You can't catch it anywhere anyway.

The only concern would be that `std::terminate` might be called at any unspecified point in `main` prior to the first odr-use and in any thread.