# Avoid unused variables get optimized out in C++?

Tags: c++, linker, compiler-optimization, auto-registration

I am trying to use the side effect of constructing an unused variable so I don't want it to be optimized out.

OK, I know that using side effect in constructing a variable may not be good practice. So please allow me to explain the current situation.

I have an abstract class and a concrete class. I have implemented a factory that produce `Abstract*` pointers to concrete class. For any concrete class who wishes to be produced by the abstract class, they must be registered first. Here is a minimum (non-)working example:

```cpp
// Abstract.hpp
#pragma once

class Abstract {
public:
    virtual void Hello() const = 0;
};
```

```cpp
// Abstract.cc
#include "Abstract.hpp"
#include "Factory.hpp"

template<>
Factory<Abstract>* Factory<Abstract>::_the_factory = nullptr;
```

```cpp
// Concrete.hpp
#include "Abstract.hpp"
#include "iostream"

class Concrete : public Abstract {
public:
    void Hello() const override {
        std::cerr << "B" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

```cpp
// Concrete.cc
#include "Concrete.hpp"
#include "Factory.hpp"

const bool concrete_registered = Factory<Abstract>::GetInstance()->Register("concrete", []() {
    return new Concrete;
});
```

```cpp
// Factory.hpp
#pragma once
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <class Product>
class Factory {
public:
    using ProductCreator = std::function<Product*()>;

    static Factory* GetInstance() {
        if (!_the_factory) {
            _the_factory = new Factory;
        }
        return _the_factory;
    }

    bool Register(const std::string& name, const ProductCreator& creator) {
        bool result = _creator_map.insert(std::make_pair(name, creator)).second;
        if (result) {
            std::cerr << name << " registered" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cerr << name << " can't be registered" << std::endl;
        }
        return result;
    }

    Product* GetProduct(const std::string& name) {
        if (_creator_map.find(name) == _creator_map.end()) {
            std::cerr << "Unknown product name " << name << " detected";
        }
        return _creator_map[name]();
    }

private:
    static Factory* _the_factory;
    std::map<std::string, ProductCreator> _creator_map;
};
```

I was hoping, by making `concrete_registered` a constant, I can force the program to execute the registration code before `main` so that I can get the product of `Concrete` from the factory. Here is how I use them:

```cpp
// main.cc
#include "Abstract.hpp"
#include "Factory.hpp"

int main() {
    auto ptr = Factory<Abstract>::GetInstance()->GetProduct("concrete");
    ptr->Hello();
}
```

The whole project has the following structure:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── lib
│   ├── Abstract.cc
│   ├── Abstract.hpp
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── Concrete.cc
│   ├── Concrete.hpp
│   └── Factory.hpp
└── main.cc
```

And my `CMakeLists.txt` are:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

add_subdirectory(lib)
add_executable(main main.cc)
target_link_libraries(main lib)
```

```
# lib/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(lib Abstract.cc Concrete.cc)
target_include_directories(lib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

However, I got the following error when running the program:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_function_call'
```

And indeed I did not see the log indicating a successful registration of the `Concrete` objects (Note the logging in `Factory.hpp`)

After spending some time searching about this problem, I realize this may be the result of  variable `concrete_registered` being unused so the linker does not link it to the main program. That is why I need to use the side effect of constructing for an unused variable.

My question: Is it possible to force C++ linker to link `concrete_registered` to the main program? I know some tricks like `-Wl,--whole-archive -lXXX -Wl,--no-whole-archive` but I am afraid linking the whole target may be too much, I just need this part of the code 'not optimized out'

Comment: when it has observable side effects then it cannot be optimized out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule

Comment: I didnt spot it yet in the code, but the error smells like you are calling a virtual method in a constructor

Comment: *I am trying to use the side effect of constructing an unused variable so I don't want it to be optimized out.* -- This has to be one of the biggest code smells around.  When or if you change compiler or compiler version, or compiler options, and whatever trick you come up with fails to work when it did before, you're right back to square one again.

Comment: Initialization of global might be deferred after `main`.

Comment: And as you didn't ODR-used anything in that TU, it is never initialized.

Comment: [OT]: For singleton, you might use Meyers' Singleton, i.e `static Factory& GetInstance() { static Factory instance; return instance; }`.

Comment: This is not because an unused variable is not initialised. This is because an unreferenced member of an archive is not a part of the program. (I.e. not a C++ issue but a linker issue). You don't have a lot of options. Either do not create an archive (you may use individual objects or a shared library instead), or use `--whole-archive`.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI is exactly correct, although I will clarify that "member of an archive" means an **entire compilation unit**, unless you are working with non-standard options like Microsoft's COMDAT "Function Level Linking".

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Hi, thanks for the reply. However, when I use that link option, it can generate multiple definition errors if there is diamond dependence. Guess I have to avoid such code then.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Thanks for your reply. I tried to output the value of `concrete_registered` in `Hello` of `Concrete` class. However, the error persists. It seems that if `Hello` of `Concrete` class is not explicitly called, it will not be linked.

Comment: sorry, my comment was refering to your title, but as n.m. explained the issue is not a compiler optimization that you need to prevent from happening. Hence my first comments are not that relevant for your actual issue. I thought they might be useful nevertheless for you to understand that an optimization cannot change observable behavior

Comment: If you have a multiple definitions error, there is a bug in your code. You may want to ask a question about that error.

Comment: I tried in visual studio debug and release, both work.  You are stressing the language, I think its to do with the static initialization fiasco, where code generated relies on complex types such as map before the main has run, which is not a great pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Reading better, this is a side effect of how libraries work.  When you have a library mylib.a, it has a number of object files

file1.o, file2.o, file3.o

These are pulled into the binary by the linker, when they are referenced.  Your system creates concrete.o, with no exported data, so it won't get added by the linker to your binary.  The linker can't see the abstract lookup from main.cc to the factory (implemented in main.cc), and figure that for the system to work it needs concrete.o to be added to the binary.

Try using objdump to see where implementations are.

You need to have a symbol from your concrete class to be pulled into you binary, or it will not work